# strtotime february bug

Tags: php, strtotime

Okay, so I do understand that if I am running the strtotime function on a day that is the 29th or higher I will incur the February bug and get a result for March instead.

Also I get that if I set the date to Feb 1st, I can avoid the issue.

But here is the problem. I am rolling through the last 12 months of records to generate sales/billing numbers for tracking. How do I ask for all records in February when my loop looks like this?

```
setlocale( LC_MONETARY, 'en_US' );

$i = 0;
while( $i <= 11 ) {                 
  $select = "SELECT * FROM `my_table` " . 
            "WHERE YEAR( billing_date )  = '" . date( 'Y', strtotime( -$i . ' month' )) . "' " . 
            "  AND MONTH( billing_date ) = '" . date( 'm', strtotime( -$i . ' month' )) . "'";

  $result   = mysql_query( $select );
  $num_rows = mysql_num_rows( $result );

  $sales    = 16 * $num_rows;

  echo "<p align='center'>";
  echo   "Sales for " . date( 'M, Y', strtotime( '-' . $i . ' month' ) ) .
         "&nbsp" . money_format( '%i', $sales );
  echo "</p>";

  $i++;
}
```

How do I avoid the February bug? Would it be an `if` statement? What would that look like?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a bug. Februari actually has only 28 days. Or at least it did in 1970.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to fetch with that query. `MONTH(billing_date)` will return a number from 1 to 12, so why aren't you just comparing with `$i+1`?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pure SQL solution (if I correctly understand the scenario):

```sql
SELECT 
    YEAR(billing_date) AS billing_year,  
    MONTH(billing_date) AS billing_month,
    16 * COUNT(*) AS sales /* Why x16?!!! */
FROM my_table
GROUP BY YEAR(billing_date), MONTH(billing_date)
```

This will calculate the sales directly in SQL, so in PHP you just need a display loop.

Comment: /* Why x16?!! */ because it is the dollar value for each sale. So it ends up showing the total sales revenue for the month. I am going to have to play with the output of this. I understand what you wrote, just not sure on how to display it. I am sure I will figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Tom, I was curious :). I just edited the answer adding aliases to the computed columns, so you'll be able to access them with `$row['billing_year']` etc, inside your `while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))` loop.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I ask for all records in February...

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MONTH(billing_date) = 2

Comment: This will return all records for every February. If you want only records from e.g. 2011 make sure to specify the year also: `AND YEAR( billing_date ) = 2011`.

Answer (score 0):

February bug? It's not a bug. Normalizing dates is a (useful) feature! :-)

If you want the last day in February, ask for the 0th of March.

Comment: True. It is normalizing not a real bug. Then again strtotime is so versatile, it just seems that asking for everything from a table in February should not be effected by what day I am asking it from. Just the way I view it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the "february bug", but you could try to use MySQL to subtract 1 month. Check

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(billing_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) FROM my_table
```

=> [Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)